# BeautifulSoup does not return all the elements in a page that looks like other

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the same code in Python to extract the results of matches of this federation and it works on all pages except in this Group 3 (two example links below)

[Group 2 - working](https://rfetm.es/resultados/2022-2023/view.php?liga=Mg==&grupo=2&subgrupo=S&jornada=1&sexo=M)

[Group 3 - not working](https://rfetm.es/resultados/2022-2023/view.php?liga=Mg==&grupo=3&subgrupo=S&jornada=1&sexo=M)

The code looks for all the tables with the `soup.find_all("table", class_="table-sm")` and it returns a variable number of tables depending on the number of matches on the page that begin at table 4 and that I use to get the results.

When the same code is applied to Group 3, it only returns 2: the second one contains all content below the head of the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_gr_2 = 'https://rfetm.es/resultados/2022-2023/view.php?liga=Mg==&grupo=2&subgrupo=S&jornada=1&sexo=M'
url_gr_3 = 'https://rfetm.es/resultados/2022-2023/view.php?liga=Mg==&grupo=3&subgrupo=S&jornada=1&sexo=M'

req = requests.get(url_gr_2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, features="lxml")
data = soup.find_all("table", class_="table-sm")
print(len(data))
# returns 9

req = requests.get(url_gr_3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, features="lxml")
data = soup.find_all("table", class_="table-sm")
print(len(data))
# returns 2
```

I was using a Chrome selector extension and the console to test the structure of the page of Group 3 and it returns 8 elements on the page, but not in bs4.

I was also trying to iterate over the HTML elements of the `data[1]` in the case of the Group 3 but bs4 do not return any element.

I tried to compare the HTML of both pages but I was not able to find any significative difference.

What I expected is to be able to extract the results of this league as I do with all the rest of the leagues in this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html.parser` or `html5lib` as a parser for this page. `lxml` is more strict and it doesn't parse this page as a browser does.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rfetm.es/resultados/2022-2023/view.php?liga=Mg==&grupo=3&subgrupo=S&jornada=1&sexo=M'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')  # <-- use `html.parser`

data = soup.find_all("table", class_="table-sm")
print(len(data))
```

Prints:

```
8
```

Comment: Many thanks, Andrej. 

It also turns out that it perfectly works in WSL but not in Windows. 

C'est la vie!!!